# How to run Selenium tests in GitHub Actions

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, github-actions

**I'm trying to find the equivalent command to run Selenium tests in GitHub actions**. In Azure DevOps, I'd use this YAML to run "Visual Studio Test":

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run functional smoke tests on website and web service'
  inputs:
    searchFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\FeatureFlags.FunctionalTests\FeatureFlags.FunctionalTests.dll
    uiTests: true
    runSettingsFile: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/drop/FunctionalTests/FeatureFlags.FunctionalTests/test.runsettings'
    overrideTestrunParameters: |
     -ServiceUrl "https://$(WebServiceName)-staging.azurewebsites.net/" 
     -WebsiteUrl "https://$(WebsiteName)-staging.azurewebsites.net/"
```

In GitHub actions, what is the equivalent task? It doesn't look like the VsTest.Console.exe exists in the GitHub runner/agent, so the answer may involve installing the [Visual Studio Test Platform installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/vstest-platform-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) - but obviously I'd like to avoid this as this would severely slow down each build.

Comment: It seems runners already got Visual Studio Enterprise check this [link](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/software-installed-on-github-hosted-runners#windows-server-2019)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I've found it at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe. I'll try this out and see if it works.

Comment: btw, I found it by searching the agent with (I'll clean this up at the end)

    - name: search for visual studio test runner
      run: |
        $var1 = Get-Childitem -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio" -Filter "vstest.console.exe" -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName
        Write-Host "VS test runner: $var1"
      shell: powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Eldar who helped point me in the right direction. The basic answer is (running in a Windows runner):

```
- name: Functional Tests
  run: |
    $vsTestConsoleExe = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\TestPlatform\\vstest.console.exe"
    $targetTestDll = "functionaltests\FeatureFlags.FunctionalTests.dll"
    $testRunSettings = "/Settings:`"functionaltests\test.runsettings`" "
    #Note that the `" is an escape character to quote strings, and the `& is needed to start the command
    $command = "`& `"$vsTestConsoleExe`" `"$targetTestDll`" $testRunSettings " 
    Write-Host "$command"
    Invoke-Expression $command
  shell: powershell
```

Using Invoke-Expression seemed to help with some initial errors I was receiving. The complete yaml, with context, is viewable on [GitHub](https://github.com/samsmithnz/SamsFeatureFlags/blob/master/.github/workflows/aspnetcore.yml):

Note to find the vstest.console.exe file, I used this yaml to search the GitHub Actions runner. There are folders that are locked, so this throws an error if you search on the root C: folder. With the [link](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/software-installed-on-github-hosted-runners#windows-server-2019) provided above, I was able to establish that the root folder for Visual Studio and search for vstest.console.exe there:

```
- name: search for visual studio test runner
  run: |
    $var1 = Get-Childitem -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio" -Filter "vstest.console.exe" -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName
    Write-Host "VS test runner: $var1"
  shell: powershell
```

Answer (score 1):

This is now a lot simplier thanks to the [Setup VSTeset.console.exe](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-vstest-console-exe) action that is available on the Marketplace.

It still requires running on a Windows agent but the number of YAML lines is significantly reduced.

The following snippet assumes that an artifact named "functional-tests" that contains the compiled assets (DLLs, chromedriver.exe etc) for your Selenium tests has been [uploaded](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/upload-a-build-artifact) then [downloaded](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/download-a-build-artifact) into "./functional-tests/".

```
- name: Add VSTest.console.exe to the PATH
  uses: darenm/Setup-VSTest@v1

- name: Run functional tests
  run: vstest.console.exe "functional-tests\<functional-tests-project-dll-name-here>.dll"
```

My experience has been that if you set [environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables#about-environment-variables) at the job level, these will automatically be picked up by `vstest.console.exe`. This probably holds true for setting them at the step or workflow level but I have not tested that.